# Does Rails have a per request store that I can add objects to and retrieve from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In asp.net there is something called Request.Items that I can add an object to, and then I can check to see if an object is present in the .Items collection from another part of my code (like in another class).

Does Rails have something like this?

Comment: The question is : what do you really want to store and what is the longevity of the object you want to store ?
Do you want to store object only for the current request, for 1 redirection, or for all request (like configuration variables/constants) ?

Comment: @slainer I want to store objects for a single request only, without using session etc.  (asp.net's request.items doesn't rely on session/memcache/database)

Comment: Can you explain why?  There might be a more 'rails' way to do this.

Comment: you should be able to put stuff into 'env' if you are in the context of the request ie controller or view

Answer (score 3):

One of the most popular options is to use the [`request_store`](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store) gem, which allows you to access a global store that you from any part of your code. It uses `Thread.current` to store your data, and takes care of cleaning up the data after each request.

```
RequestStore[:items] = []
```

Be aware though, since it uses `Thread.current`, it won't work properly in a multi-threaded environment where you have more than one thread per request.

To circumvent this problem, I have implemented a store that can be shared between threads for the same request. It's called [`request_store_rails`](https://github.com/ElMassimo/request_store_rails), and the usage is very similar:

```
RequestLocals[:items] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

You may define a class method (in any class you want) to store your data:

```
class Xyzzy
  def self.items
    @items ||= {}
  end
end
# ....
if Xyzzy.items.include? :fubar
  Xyzzy.items[:asd] = 1
end
```

But you should decide when you want this 'cache' to be cleared. If you want it only for one request, define a before_filter which will call `Xyzzy.items.clear`

The class objects are global. You may also use a standard global variable, but that would be less elegant. :)

Comment: but I would then want to reference this from say a Module I have, possible?

Comment: Yes, you can. In some modules (if they also define a class with the same name) you may need to use `::Xyzzy.items`, but in general, the class objects are visible everywhere.

Comment: Note this isn't thread-safe. You probably want to use something involving Thread.current